# What documents are needed to justify the funds transferred in bulk indicated in my bank statement, to be submitted for UK visitor visa application?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, standard-visitor-visas

I am a student currently pursuing my studies in Belgium. My home country is different from where I currently study. I wish to visit my friend in the UK this upcoming spring break and I am planning to apply for a UK Standard visitor visa. As tou know, to apply for a visa I have to provide financial documents supporting my financial stability.

In my case, my parents are supporting me for my expenses and studies in Europe, and in the last 5 months, I have received bulk funds (around 3,000 euros + 4,000 euros in the last 6 months) for my studies and expenses (conservative approach for future expenses).

Currently I have an adequate  balance (from those amounts) in my bank and I wish to use this bank balance/statement to support my UK tourist visa application.

Since I am a student who doesn't have any stable income, do those bulk transaction details in my bank statement create a chance of visa refusal due to the question of source of fund? If yes, what additional documents can I attach to justify these transfers and balance currently in my account?

*** FYI, my parents have been retired for the last 2 years and the funds they transferred to me are from their personal savings. So I do not have any documents such as my parents' latest pay-slip or income statement.

Answer (score 2):

It's advisable to include a letter from your parents explaining the source of the funds, confirming their retirement status, and expressing their support for your studies and trip. You can also provide any documents showing their retirement, like pension statements or retirement certificates, to strengthen your application. Good luck with your visa application.

You can check the official website for other information's
https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/uk-visas-and-immigration

Comment: Proof of your parents' wealth/income is probably more important than proof of retirement. The immigration people are interested in money.

Comment: Yeah, totally get that.